# What does "$g$ and $-g^{-1}$ are homologous" mean?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, definition

> If $g$ is a (not necessarily closed) path in X, prove that the $1$-chain $g$ is homologous to $-g^{-1}$.

What exactly does it mean for these two $1$-chains to be homologous?  Does it mean $\text{ cls } g = \text{ cls } (-g^{-1})$?  And if so what exactly is a negative chain imply?

Comment: Two chains $a,b$ are homologous if there is $c \in C_2(X)$ such that $\partial c = a - b$, or equivalenty as you wrote $[a] = [b]$ in $H_1(X)$. So you need to find such $c$ with $\partial c = g - g^{-1}$.

Comment: @N.H. Wouldn't I have to find a $c$ such that $\partial c = g - (-g^{-1}) = g + g^{-1}$ since it's asking to show the homologous relationship between $g$ and $-g^{-1}$?

Comment: Oh yes sure sorry. But I saw you did open a previous question with the same question, which contained the answer, since $g $ and $- g^{-1}$ are homotopic so in particular homologous.

Comment: @N.H. If you're referring to this question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319663/if-f-is-a-not-necessarily-closed-path-in-x-prove-that-the-1-chain-f-i, you're saying I solved the answer in the question?  Could you explain how I solved it?  I'm still trying to figure that out.

Comment: Ok, first we have $[g \cdot g^{-1}] = e_{\pi_1}$ in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ with $x_0$ =g(0)$ and $e_{\pi_1}$ the class of the constant path. This means that $[g + g^{-1}] = 0$, in particular that $[g] = [-g^{-1}]$ in $H_1(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

When we say that $c$ is homologous to $c'$, we usually mean they represent the same element in the homology group, that is, $[c] = [c']$, as you expected. This, however, only makes sense when $c$ and $c'$ are cycles. if they are not, we can still call them *homologous* if
$$
c - c' = \partial b
$$
for some $2$-chain $b$. Note that this means $c-c'$ is a cycle, so only $1$-chains with the same boundary can be homologous.

An example of a situation where this extended definition of *homologous* is opportune is when we compare the fundamental group of a based space $(X,x_0)$ with the homology group $H_1(X)$. Here homotopic pathes $f$ and $g$ give rise to homologous simplices $f,g: \Delta^1 \to X$. We therefore have a map $\pi_1(X,x_0) \to H_1(X)$.